# Почему MessageBox не выводит html?

Tags: c#, winforms, cefsharp, .net-5

Хочу получить html код страницы. Для этого использую CefSharp, так-как на сайте есть защита ввиде капчи. Решил использовать

```
string source = await browser.GetBrowser().MainFrame.GetSourceAsync();
```

были проблемы с deadlock, но вроде смотря через дебаг, код не умирает после этой строчки. Доходит до MessageBox и ничего не выводится!

Код:

```
 private async void Browser_FrameLoadEnd(object sender, FrameLoadEndEventArgs e)
        {
            string source = await browser.GetBrowser().MainFrame.GetSourceAsync();
 
            MessageBox.Show(source);
        }
```

фото из программы:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Я думаю, следует использовать `FrameLoadEndEventArgs `. Обращаться к его свойству `e.Frame` и так далее.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте запустить через [`BeginInvoke`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke?view=net-5.0) формы:

```
BeginInvoke(new Action(() => MessageBox.Show(source)));
```

Для того чтобы отобразить сообщение `MessageBox.Show` должен выполняться в потоке UI. Когда он выполняется в другом потоке (async), то сообщение не отображается и этот поток блокируется, т.к. метод ожидает действие пользователя. В результате приложение зависает.

Comment: Не работает, но почему-то теперь весь интерфейс зависает.

Comment: @ХачатунАждаак Так получилось, или нет?

Comment: не, не работает. Я обдумываю комментарий Алексея петрова.

Comment: @ХачатунАждаак Понятно. В таком случае лучше снимите галочку на моем ответе. Вопросы без принятых ответов получают больше внимания.